# jquery ui tooltip accordian bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have ran into what might be a unique problem. I've tried figuring it out, but can't find any evidence for what could be causing it. I am using Jquery UI tooltips in my web app. I need to manually position them. So what I do is position a 1px x 1px div where I want it, load up the content of the tooltip with custom HTML, and then open the tooltip. It works perfectly, except for under one case.

I also have a jquery ui accordian as my left side menu. When the first panel of the accordion is open, the tooltips work fine. They show up exactly where I want them. When any other accordion panel is open, the tooltips always show up in the upper left hand corner of the screen. The tooltip div has the correct position set in its css property, it just doesn't show up there.

Comment: You can use the `position` option to... well, position your tooltip widgets relative to the document or even the window. Why do you need a `<div>`?

Comment: Because you need a jquery object to apply the tooltip function too. I am using tooltips in response to mouse events over an HTML 5 canvas. So when I decide I need to open a tooltip, I put that div where the mouse is so the tooltip has something to open on. I guess you could out that div anywhere right, and use position every time to say where it should go? But will that still have collision detection? I want the tooltip to appear to the upper right of the mouse when near the bottom of the window, and lower right near the top. It does that now, except for the accordion bug.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your code? I'm pretty sure you can position the tooltip to the current cursor location by passing the related event to `position()`, or probably even in the `position` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb now. Should I delete this question?

My tooltip div was INSIDE the accordion, for unknown reasons. I don't remember who put it there, or why it ended up there. I moved it to the end of the document, and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, I'm guessing. My guess is that you're positioning your 1x1 divs with JS, and because your accordion panels are {display: none} at that time, they have no size to reference for positioning.

You'll need to position your 1x1 divs *after* each accordion action,

OR

set your accordion panels offscreen, but not hidden, with `{position: absolute; left: -999em; display: block;}`